# Convert Numpy matrix to list with indices as tuples

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix (could be numpy matrix, could be scipy sparse matrix):

```
np.array([[0,2,3], [1,0,5], [3,3,4]])

array([[0, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 5],
       [3, 3, 4]])
```

What I would like is to convert this to a dictionary, where keys are a tuple of the indices and the value is the entry in the matrix as follows, for non zero elements:

```
{(0,1): 2,
 (0,2): 3,
 (1,0): 1,
 (1,2): 5,
 (2,0): 3,
 (2,1): 3,
 (2,2): 4}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There's a slight difference between the specification in the subject line and the text.  List of tuple or dictionary?  Are you aware of a `sparse` format that is a subclass of `dict`?

Answer (score 4):

as per [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,2,3], [1,0,5], [3,3,4]])
print({index:x for index, x in np.ndenumerate(a) if x})
```

Output:

```
  {(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 0): 1, (1, 2): 5, (2, 0): 3, (2, 1): 3, (2, 2): 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using for loops:

```py
x = np.array([[0,2,3], [1,0,5], [3,3,4]])

my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j, elem in enumerate(x[i]):
        if(elem):
            my_dict[(i,j)] = elem

print(my_dict)
>>> {(0, 1): 2,
 (0, 2): 3,
 (1, 0): 1,
 (1, 2): 5,
 (2, 0): 3,
 (2, 1): 3,
 (2, 2): 4}
```

Comment: And you add `if(elem):` juste before `my_dict[(i,j)] = elem`

Comment: @Clément yes thank you, you are absolutely correct, I did not notice that he only wanted non-zero elements. Thanks for the comment, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Every answer here loops over the whole matrix which is **inefficient if `N x M >> #nnz`**, where `N` and `M` are the dimensions of your matrix and `#nnz` the number of non-zero elements.

My solution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def get_nnz_dict(m):
    nnz_idx = m.nonzero()
    nnz_dict = {}
    for idx in range(len(nnz_idx[0])):
        row, col = nnz_idx[0][idx], nnz_idx[1][idx]
        nnz_dict[(row,col)] = m[row,col]
    return nnz_dict

M = np.array([[0,2,3], [1,0,5], [3,3,4]])
M_sp = csr_matrix(M)
nnz_dict = get_nnz_dict(M)
nnz_dict_sp = get_nnz_dict(M_sp)
```

Works for "normal" numpy array as well as for scipy sparse matrices.

Comment: Why not `sparse.dok_matrix(m)`?

Comment: Actually never heard of that function before, thanks :) But still, if you like to have only nnz entries you have to sort out the zeros.